# Free database of polymers with Hansen parameters

Tags: solubility, polymers

I am developing a product that needs a component to expand when in contact with crude oil.

Found the wikipedia article about Hanses solubility parameters and thought it would be a good idea to run the parameters of crude oil against a list of polymers to find maybe the five closest polymers.

Where can I find a database of solvents and polymers online?

It should be noted that I know very little about chemistry, but enough about computer programming to be able to run the test against any database format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that due to copyright claims the only database available is [HSPiP](https://www.hansen-solubility.com/buy-HSPiP-software.php), plus there is the most recent handbook [Hansen, C. M. Hansen solubility parameters: a user’s handbook, 2nd ed.; CRC Press: Boca Raton, 2007](https://www.crcpress.com/Hansen-Solubility-Parameters-A-Users-Handbook-Second-Edition/Hansen/p/book/9780849372483). The book costs ten times less than a database and contains tables for solvents on pp. 345 -- 485, and for polymers on pp. 487 -- 500.